# How to get around the "couldn't match type 'b' with ConcreteType"?

Tags: haskell

The architecture is as follows: a user generates an Intent, which is then captured by the system. The Resolver finds an appropriate function that can resolve this intent. There is an index that maps Intents to Modules that have mentioned their capabilities in these intents. The basic idea is that a module takes an entity and generates another entity as a result.

I tried ExistentialTypes but I don't think I have enough expertise to work with them yet, so I'd like to know if there's a simpler way.

An entity looks like this.

```hs
data Entity a = Entity {...}

data DirectionEntity = DirectionEntity {...}
```

There are lots of entities.

A handler looks like this:

```hs
handler :: Entity NavigationEntity -> IO (Entity DirectionEntity)
```

I want to have some information at the type level.
Everything is fine until I want to have a single data structure that contains all these handlers, in one place. Basically, I would like to have a function like:

```hs
solveIntent :: Intent -> Entity a -> IO (Entity b)
solveIntent intent entity = do
  index <- mkIndex
  let m = searchModule index intent
  run m entity
```

And here's the problem in the title: I can't match the types:

```hs
Expected type: Entity a -> IO (Entity b)
Actual type: Entity NavigationEntity -> IO (Entity DirectionEntity)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `a` and `b` are universally quantified. So if you write `solveIntent :: Intent -> Entity a -> IO (Entity b)` then it means that the function holds for *all* `a`s and `b`s. But that is not the case here. Since you likely use functions like `searchModule` that are specific for `NavigationEntity`, etc.

Comment: I understand that I can make every handler to be of type `Entity a -> IO (Entity b)`. But that would mean I lose type information.

Comment: @dciug You would only lose type information which doesn't exist...? That `b` is simply incorrect in your type signature.

Comment: @dciug: but that is indeed exactly the problem: by writing `solveIndent` as `solveIndent :: Intent -> Entity a -> IO (Entity b)`, it indeed loses information, likely type information you need in the *body* (the expression) of your `solveIntent` function.

Comment: Ok. Then how do I make it so that I can pass any kind of entity? There could be a lot of entities in the system.

Comment: In order to pass any kind of entity, it looks like you need handlers for all of them, and some way to dispatch each entity to the correct handler. Your example doesn't demonstrate how that happens.

Comment: `Intent -> Entity a -> IO (Entity b)` doesn't mean that `solveIntent` can handle *any* entity; it *promises* that it can handle *every* entity.

Comment: can you add the full code? from `data` and functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A data type like `Intent` exposes no type information. The type of an `Intent` for `NavigationEntity -> DirectionEntity` is the same as the type of an `Intent` for `DirectionEntity -> NavigationEntity`. Therefore, the type of the result of `searchModule` cannot change based on the `Intent`, and you have a problem, because that's the point.

Stepping back, you have a huge collection of `exists a b. Entity a -> IO (Entity b)`s. You want to be able to pick two `Type`s—`a` and `b`—and search your collection for a matching function. This is a job for `Typeable`: You need to define a type to hold each `exists a b. Entity a -> IO (Entity b)`, plus `Typeable` evidence for `a` and `b`, and then `lookupModule` should take `Typeable` evidence for the two types you're searching for. You don't need an `Intent` or whatever. You just need the type of the module you are searching for. The simplest collection type to deal with is just `[]`.

```
import Data.Type.Equality
import Type.Reflection

data DirectionEntity deriving Typeable -- needs DeriveDataTypeable extension
data NavigationEntity deriving Typeable

data SomeModule =
  -- needs ExistentialQuantification, ExplicitForAll extensions
  forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => 
  SomeModule (Entity a -> IO (Entity b))

type ModuleIndex = [SomeModule]
handler :: Entity NavigationEntity -> IO (Entity DirectionEntity)
index :: ModuleIndex
index = [SomeModule handler] -- or whatever

-- really, this is more of a mapMaybe/filter than a lookup
lookupModule ::
  forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => -- needs ScopedTypeVariables
  ModuleIndex -> [Entity a -> IO (Entity b)] -- can have any number of matches!
lookupModule [] = []
-- we have a, b, which are our search queries
-- we extract x, y from the `SomeModule`
-- we have Typeable for all four, so we check for a match
-- then decide whether or not to include the function
-- (well, *we* don't really decide; without a match, it's a type error!)
lookupModule (SomeModule (x :: Entity x -> IO (Entity y)) : xs)
  -- needs GADTs, TypeOperators extensions
  | Just Refl <- testEquality typeRep typeRep :: Maybe (a :~: x)
  , Just Refl <- testEquality typeRep typeRep :: Maybe (b :~: y)
  = x : lookupModule xs
  | otherwise = lookupModule xs
```

Which should give you something like

```
> length (lookupModule index :: [Entity NavigationEntity -> IO (Entity DirectionEntity)]) 
1
> length (lookupModule index :: [Entity DirectionEntity -> IO (Entity NavigationEntity)])
0
```

If your collection is *really* big, you may want to use a `Map`. This gets hairier, because we're using unsafe operations, but the interface is still safe. This should get its own module, for access control.

```
module ModuleIndex(ModuleIndex, SomeModule(..), fromList, lookupModule) where

import Type.Reflection
import Unsafe.Coerce

import Data.Map as M

data Key = forall (a :: Type) (b :: Type). Key (TypeRep a) (TypeRep b)
instance Eq Key where
  Key a b == Key x y =
    SomeTypeRep a == SomeTypeRep x && SomeTypeRep b == SomeTypeRep y
instance Ord Key where
  compare (Key a b) (Key x y) =
    compare (SomeTypeRep a) (SomeTypeRep x) <> compare (SomeTypeRep b) (SomeTypeRep y)
data Value = forall a b. Value (Entity a -> IO (Entity b))

newtype ModuleIndex = ModuleIndex { getModuleIndex :: Map Key Value }
data SomeModule =
  forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => 
  SomeModule (Entity a -> IO (Entity b))
fromList :: [SomeModule] -> ModuleIndex
fromList = ModuleIndex . M.fromList . fmap disentangle
  where disentangle (SomeModule (f :: Entity a -> IO (Entity b))) =
          (Key (typeRep :: TypeRep a) (typeRep :: TypeRep b), Value f)
lookupModule ::
  forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b) =>
  ModuleIndex -> Maybe (Entity a -> IO (Entity b))
lookupModule = fmap extract . M.lookup key . getModuleIndex
  where key = Key (typeRep :: TypeRep a) (typeRep :: TypeRep b)
        extract (Value f) = unsafeCoerce f :: Entity a -> IO (Entity b)
```

Comment: I've been looking through the docs for a few hours to understand this and I learned a lot. This works but the reason I was thinking about Intents is because the system is linked to an NLP module, which extracts the intents from a textual request from a user.

Comment: For now I have to manually specify the result type of the `lookupModule` function. Can I deduce that automatically at runtime? Something like: take the `typeOf` this varialbe and the `typeOf` that variable and then lookup the index.

Comment: Type information (`Typeable`) is not attached to variables. Type information is attached to types. Having a variable `x :: a`, and having type information `Typeable a` are simply not related. For your use case I might try something like `data SomeEntity = forall a. Typeable a => SomeEntity (Entity a); data WithSomeEntity r = forall a. Typeable a => WithSomeEntity (Entity a -> r); handleInput :: UserInput -> (SomeEntity, WithSomeEntity Result)`, but I'd need more details to be sure.